# preventing Buffer overflow when pwfeedback is set in the sudoers file

Tags: command-line, linux-mint, security, sudo

I am using **Linux Mint 19.3**. For a few days, there is an explanation that the `sudoers` file has buffer overflow if the `sudo` version is between 1.7.1 to 1.8.25p1.

And there is a command to see if you are affected by the explosion.

If the `sudo -l` command’s output contains `'pwfeedback` in it, you are affected.

You should change the sudoers file with `!pwfeedback`.

Although sudoers file doesn't contain it, when I check with `sudo -l`, the output is like that:

```
Matching Defaults entries for da on of:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin, pwfeedback

User da may run the following commands on of:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
    (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mint-refresh-cache
    (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/linuxmint/mintUpdate/synaptic-workaround.py
    (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/linuxmint/mintUpdate/dpkg_lock_check.sh
```

But the output of the `sudoers` file does not contain `pwfeedback`.

```
da@of:~$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

The `/etc/sudoers.d/0pwfeedback` file has just one line and contains it. When I prepend `!` to `pwfeedback` and run the command `sudo -l`, the output does not change. Again it has `!pwfeedback`.

I am a little bit confused. Am I affected by the vulnerability?
And how to make `pwfeedback` disappear not to be affected by this vulnerability?

Comment: But it has potential to affect all Ubuntu flavours right? Also askubuntu has a 'mint' tag.

Comment: So I have nothing to do or just editing /etc/sudoers.d/0pwfeedback file and adding ! is enough?

Comment: Related: [Password asterisk feedback mysteriously enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884425/password-asterisk-feedback-mysteriously-enabled)

Comment: FYI: `pwfeedback` is enabled by default on Mint but *NOT* on Linux.  This issue you stated only affects Mint currently because unless someone turned on pwfeedback on Ubuntu it doesn't affect the default SSH config on Ubuntu.  I am going to migrate this to Unix and Linux because this is on topic there due to Mint being the only factor here.

Comment: Thank you all for your kindness.

Comment: Your safe because you have the next line commented out `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d` which avoids the load of `0pwfeedback`. If you ever uncoment that becouse you insert a file there for configuration purposes you might be in trouble.

Comment: @YoMismo It looks weird but `#includedir` is not a comment, see [`man sudoers`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers). OP has also checked the actual behavior using `sudo -l`.

Comment: The one weird thing is that if i add ! to pwfeedback, it has to be disappear on sudo -l but has not. Appears as what it is on 0pwfeedback file. So I had doubt if I am in trouble or not.

Comment: @melebius it doesn't look that weird if you think with the C hat, thanks for pointing it out, then he might be in trouble ;)

Comment: _“The one weird thing is that if i add ! to pwfeedback, it has to be disappear on sudo -l but has not.“_ I don’t think so. `!` is often used as [_not_ in programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation#Programming), so if you get `!pwfeedback` in the output, it should work well – no asterisks should appear when entering the password within `sudo`. @YoMismo Yes, it looks like an include in C, the funny thing is that `sudoers` also uses `#` to mark comments, unlike C.